# Front-end entry form not updating custom fields in existing entry

Tags: entry-form

I have an entry form (in a local v3.5.13.1 dev context) configured to update existing entries in a particular section. On load, it’s reflecting existing data (input via the Craft control panel) perfectly well, including Assets and Matrix field content.

But when I'm logged in as a **Super Admin** and I submit changes, it will receive updates to the entry `Title` field but not to any custom fields.

No errors are being reported and it redirects to the desired page.

At present, I have stripped it right back to the `Title` field and a single Plain Text custom field but no joy. Here is my form code:

```
{% set entry = entry ?? create('craft\\elements\\Entry') %}
{% set redirectUrl = "partners/#{entry.id}" %}
{% set sectionId = entry.sectionId %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
    {{ redirectInput(redirectUrl) }}
    {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '5') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('entryId', entry.id) }}
    {{ hiddenInput('entryVariable', 'badEntry'|hash) }}

    {% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}
          
    <p>
        <label class="field-below">
            <span class="field-label"><strong>Organisation name</strong></span>
            {{ input('text', 'title', entry.title, {
                required: true,
                class: entry.hasErrors('title') ? 'text error' : 'text'
            }) }}
            {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}
        </label> 
    </p>

    <p>
        <label class="field-below">
            <span class="field-label">
                <strong>Headline:</strong>
                <span class="line-ib">Optional, 10 words or fewer recommended</span>
            </span> 
            {{ input('text', 'headline', entry.headline, {
                required: true,
                class: entry.hasErrors('headline') ? 'text error' : 'text'
            }) }}
            {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('headline')) }}
        </label> 
    </p>

    <p class="field-submit">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Update page">
    </p>
</form>
```

No updates to the `Headline` field get saved. Updates to the `Title` field do. Where can I be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your custom fields in a `fields` array, try:

```
{{ input('text', 'fields[headline]', entry.headline, {
    required: true,
    class: entry.hasErrors('headline') ? 'text error' : 'text'
}) }}
```

See example here - https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-form

Comment: Thanks so much Oli, that's what I needed. It's my first time making an Entry Form. The [Entry Form doc](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/examples/entry-form.html) really ought to make this point but it doesn't!

Comment: Just talking with Matt about it so we make it more obvious :) Glad you're sorted!

Comment: Ironically all my most complex fields already had `fields[handle]` going on, but the simplest ones didn't because they were derived from the root doc!